# AlertDialog custom view is not appearing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm building a simple AlertDialog with custom layout from XML. Here is how it's supposed to look (taken from Eclipse): It's simply 4 columns:

[image]

Here is the xml of the image above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/colorpicker_dialog_color1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:tag="0xFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/colorpicker_dialog_color2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FFDD66"
        android:tag="0xFFDD66" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/colorpicker_dialog_color3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#66CCFF"
        android:tag="0x66CCFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/colorpicker_dialog_color4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#B6C0D2"
        android:tag="0xB6C0D2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of the costume Alert Dialog:

```
public void showColorPickerDialog() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View layout = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.color_picker_dialog, null);

        ImageView clr1 = (ImageView) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.colorpicker_dialog_color1);

        clr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // .. code
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("cccc");

        builder.setView(layout)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).show();

    }
```

The problem is that in my dialog I dont see any column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Views` instead of `ImageViews` in your layout. The problem using `ImageViews` in your case is that since you do not specify the `src` attribute for the `ImageView`, it will display a 0x0-sized image, which leaves your views invisible.